# PostgreSQL replica where I can create triggers?

Tags: postgresql

I have some PostgreSQL triggers I'd like to write which use a reasonable amount of CPU and then `NOTIFY` if a complex pattern has happened.  These triggers are created dynamically by my app.  (The function it invokes doesn't have to be dynamic, though; just the arguments passed to the trigger.)

Is it possible to set up PostgreSQL streaming replication so that there is a master server where I do all my "normal" writes, and a set of read replicas which I connect to almost entirely to do reads... but where I can also create triggers that run on the read replica only?  ie, this would move the CPU load of the trigger from the master to the potentially large number of replicas.  (I would potentially use `pg_temp` for the function as described at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926115/drop-trigger-function-at-end-of-session-in-postgresql).)

When I try this with, eg, Amazon RDS read replicas, any attempt to create even `pg_temp.*` functions on the read replica unsurprisingly fails with `cannot execute CREATE FUNCTION in a read-only transaction`, but maybe there's some other way to configure streaming replication so that this is possible?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to set up PostgreSQL streaming replication so that there is a master server where I do all my "normal" writes, and a set of read replicas which I connect to almost entirely to do reads... but where I can also create triggers that run on the read replica only?

No, it isn't. Streaming replication is done at the block level. It has no idea what statements changed which rows, where. It's also strictly read-only. Really strictly - you can't do anything that changes the system catalogs like `pg_class` or `pg_proc` even transiently.

You might want to look into Londiste. If you create a trigger then [make it `ENABLE REPLICA`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) it can fire on writes replicated by Londiste from the master.

The [BDR project](http://2ndquadrant.com/BDR) can also be used for read-replicas. It doesn't yet support firing triggers on downstream row writes, but it's practical to implement, it just hasn't been a development priority.