# How do I create a temporary trigger in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, libpq

I'm trying to create a system in Postgres where each client can create its own subscriptions via listen + notify + triggers. I.e. the client will listen to a channel, and then create a trigger which runs notify on that channel when its conditions have been met. The issue is that I want Postgres to clean up properly in case of improper client termination (e.g. the remote client process dies). To be more specific, I want that trigger which is calling the notify to be removed as there is no longer a listener anyways. How can I accomplish this?

I've thought about having a table to map triggers to client ids and then using that to remove triggers where the client is gone, but it seems like a not so great solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to this in another question: [Drop trigger/function at end of session in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926115/drop-trigger-function-at-end-of-session-in-postgresql)

> In reasonably recent Postgres versions you can create a function in
> `pg_temp` schema:
>
> ```
> create function pg_temp.get_true() returns boolean language sql as $$ select true; $$;
> select pg_temp.get_true();
> ```
>
> This is the schema in which temporary tables are created. All its
> contents, including your function, will be deleted on end of session.
>
> You can also create triggers using temporary functions on tables. I've
> just tested this and it works as expected:
>
> ```
> create function pg_temp.ignore_writes() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
>     begin
>         return NULL;
>     end;
> $$;
> create table test (id int);
> create trigger test_ignore_writes
>     before insert, update, delete on test
>     for each row execute procedure pg_temp.ignore_writes();
> ```
>
> Because this trigger function always returns `NULL` and is `before [event]` it should make any writes to this table to be ignored. And
> indeed:
>
> ```
> insert into test values(1);
> select count(*) from test;
>  count
> -------
>      0
> ```
>
> But after logout and login this function and the trigger would not be
> present anymore, so writes would work:
>
> ```
> insert into test values(1);
> select count(*) from test;
>  count
> -------
>      1
> ```
>
> But you should be aware that this is somewhat hackish — not often used
> and might not be very thoroughly tested.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works. `CREATE TRIGGER` requires that you either own the table or have the `TRIGGER` privilege on it (which nobody in their right mind will give you, because it enables you to run arbitrary code in their name). Moreover, `CREATE TRIGGER` requires an `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table and `DROP TRIGGER` requires an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock, which can be disruptive.

Create a single trigger and keep that around.